# joomla 2.5 module override not working

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-module

I'm working for a government school and I'm trying to override the 'Latest News' module in my template. I've created the following structure in my template folder: template_name\html\mod_articles_latest\default.php

Locally it works well, overrides the module, but when I push it to the live site nothing happens. I don't have permission to see the FTP files, I can only work through the joomla admin area, so I can't do much on the joomla installation files to test anything.

My questions is: is there any way to not allow override module in Joomla 2.5? (because it seems that it is what is happening) or Am I doing something wrong, like the module name I'm using or something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm a little confused. You say it's not working when you preview it on your live site, however in your question you're asking how **not** to override the module. Which one is it? lol

Comment: check your overrides module folder permission,It has no access permission ..i think

Comment: Or if not access permissions check file ownership

Comment: Actually, I want to override it, but it only works in my local development environment. That's why I'm asking if is there any settings that turns the override off, because on the live site, nothing happens. Its not using the files I've set up to override the default module. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help, I figured out the problem. Strangely, on the live server the module being used to override the Latest news is "mod_articles_news" but locally its being used "mod_articles_latest". A guy from our team have found a very good website with the migration steps from Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 2.5 and I'd like to share it with everyone: http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-may-2012/item/740-How-to-convert-Joomla-15-template-to-Joomla-25?tmpl=component&print=1 . Cheers

Comment: @user1503733 Maybe you have a different version of PHP between the development environment and the production environment. If this were so, and you have enabled the display of errors in PHP, you will not see the errors.